# Using CTE to find recursive records failed

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I write a CTE in the procedure that to find the recursive records. If works fine before, but suddenly it stops working when I try to run it again. Here is what two table structure looks like:
[image]

[image]

Here is my code:

```
DELETE FROM [dbo].[NVA_Work_Rollup_BOM_Materials]
WHERE Product_Item_No = Ingredient_Item_No;

IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#temp', N'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #temp

CREATE TABLE #temp (Product nvarchar(32),
                Ingredient nvarchar(32),
                Trail nvarchar(max),
                Loopcheck BIT
                )
TRUNCATE TABLE #temp

DECLARE @False AS BIT,
    @True  AS BIT

SET     @False = 0
SET     @True  = 1;

WITH C 
as (
select       
    Product_Item_No,
    Ingredient_Item_No, 
    CAST(('|' + Product_Item_No + '|') as nvarchar(max)) as Trail,
    @False as LP
from  NVA_Work_Rollup_BOM_Materials
where
Product_Item_No in (select Item_No from NVA_Work_Rollup_Level_Codes where       Level_Code = 0 and Rpt_Period = @P_CurrentPeriod) 
AND Rpt_Period = @P_CurrentPeriod

union all

select     
    Matl.Product_Item_No,
    Matl.Ingredient_Item_No,            
    CAST((Trail + (Matl.Product_Item_No +'|')) as nvarchar(max)),
    case 
        when Trail like '%|' + CAST((Matl.Ingredient_Item_No) as nvarchar(max)) + '|%'
        then @True
        else @False
    end as LP       
from NVA_Work_Rollup_BOM_Materials as Matl
inner join C 
on C.Ingredient_Item_No = Matl.Product_Item_No
where C.LP = 0
and Matl.Rpt_Period = @P_CurrentPeriod
)

INSERT INTO #temp
SELECT * FROM C
WHERE LP = 1 
OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```

The procedure stuck on there and won't populate the #temp table. I did execution plan check, and the only thing i could see is the eager spool. Any help will be appreciate, also how should i debug here.

Comment: If you want someone to look at this problem, I would create two sample tables, add sample data and send us the script.  This is way to complicated to look at w/o data.  Also, why truncate a table that you just created?  Trust me, it will be empty.

Comment: Are you creating an endless loop "maxrecursion 0"?

Comment: Try to limit maxrecursion and I think there is a problem on your query. Try  `... union all select C.Product_Item_No, ...` instead of `... union all select Matl.Prod...`